# Non - perfect maze Generation

Tags: java, algorithm, path-finding, maze

I have coded the A* Algorithm for a project. One of the requirements of this project is to randomly generate 50 mazes.

I am a bit stuck because this is not similar to normal maze generations. In maze generations you have blocked and unblocked walls, while in my case I need to have blocked and unblocked tiles. It also can't be perfect (there should be multiple paths). I haven't really been able to find an algorithm online or description that fits this case. What would be the best way to accomplish this? I also would like to specify a starting + ending point if possible, if not then just a starting point. Thank you!

This is an example maze I manually generated (on a smaller scale):

[image]

Comment: What has this to do with an A* algorithm?

Comment: Related: [How to generate a maze with more than one successful path?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22305644/1639625)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a union-find data structure, similar to using Kruskal's algorithm to generate a maze:

- Pick start and end points
- Mark every cell except the start and end as blocked, and put each cell in its own set
- Randomly unblock cells.  When you unblock a cell, merge its set with the sets of any unblocked cells it's connected to.
- Stop when the start cell's set is merged with the end cell's set.

There will now be a path from the start to the end.  If you want to make sure that the maze is a little more open, you can keep randomly unblocking cells until, say, at least 70% are unblocked.

The result is not going to look a lot like a traditional maze, but it will probably be good for A* testing.

Comment: I was looking for a simple algorithm for an imperfect maze. This is perfect, thanks!

Comment: Also, is there a name for this algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

You could randomly assign a value (that represents blocked or un-blocked) to each tile. After you do that assign a start and end point. 
The result could look like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51120719/3992939).
If you prefer to use maze-generation algorithms use one of the widely available resources like  : [1](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm) , [2](http://www.astrolog.org/labyrnth/algrithm.htm)