# What does it mean by size of frontier and explored list in a search tree?

Tags: search, tree, breadth-first-search, fringe

I have a search tree using breadth-first search and the question asks for the largest size of frontier(fringe) and explored list.

I don't quite understand what it is asking for. I'm using a graph search so the explored node would be skipped. I've gone through my slides and even books but I still don't understand what it is asking for. Thanks.

[image: search tree using graph search (BFS)]

Answer (score 0):

BFS progress is easy to visualize as water flood. See the bottom left image in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51120719/3992939) where the grey dots represent the "flood". 
The frontier are the "front" of this "flood", which are actually the nodes that are to be evaluated next.
"The nodes that are currently evaluated" are actually those stored in the queue.
So the largest size of the frontier is equivalent to the largest size of the queue.

If you collect all the explored nodes in a list, the size of this list ("explored list") you'll have a list that keeps growing until the search is stopped.